# Formula to convert UTC date time string to date/string in different timezone

Tags: openoffice, excel

I am getting date with time in UTC format.

```
2018-12-13T03:36:11+00:00
2018-12-10T19:26:48+00:00
```

I want to convert it to date in different timezone. So take above example and the target timezone is IST(GMT+5:30) then I should get date for each as follows.

```
2018-12-13
2018-12-11
```

Comment: Do you need to do this in openoffice? In Excel? Can you just use the `date` command instead? Please [edit] your question and give us some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=(DATE(MID(A1,1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIME(MID(A1,12,2),MID(A1,15,2),MID(A1,18,2)))+5.5/24

Just select a your cell in place of "A1" in formula
and format ans cell as you want